# Swift build error_if_any_output_files_are_specified_they_all_must_be

Tags: swift, build, compiler-errors, xcode10

When converting to use the new build system on Xcode 10, I get the following error in my output for several of my extension targets.

`<unknown>:0: error: if any output files are specified, they all must be
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code`

I have looked for a solution online, but the only reference I can find to this error is in the Swift compiler source code itself.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=error_if_any_output_files_are_specified_they_all_must_be

Does anyone know how this error is actually triggered, or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: This appears to go away when I set the "Always embed swift standard libraries" flag to NO in my project settings.

This isn't really a solution, and I don't understand the mechanisms at play here.

Comment: None of the workarounds are helping for our project. This is really a showstopper, we can not archive our app at all. (normal builds using Xcode works fine, but not archiving)... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I had the same problem with one of our projects. Building or Archiving are always stopped with the error `<unknown>:0: error: if any output files are specified, they all must be`.

The **solution for us** was to set `Compilation Mode` to `Incremental` instead of `Whole Module`.

[image]

This means, you have to **ignore** the `Validate Project Settings` warning:
[image]

Comment: Good call. This saved me half a day at least ;)

Comment: Thanks. This fix also fixed the 'error: duplicate input file' problem. Can somebody explain what the reasons are behind this spell?

Comment: Thank God I found you! I can sleep now :)