# Xcode 10 (10A255) Error: <unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode10

Not sure if this is a known Xcode 10 bug or something particular about my project.  It compiles fine using Xcode 9.4.1 but when I try to compile the MacOS target project, I get a very vague error message:

```
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'WatchKit'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Extension'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Extension'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Tab'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Tab'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Files/Pods-My_WatchOS'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Extension'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Files/Pods-My_iOS'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Tests'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Support'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Tests.build'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Extension.build'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Example'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
<unknown>:0: error: if any output files are specified, they all must be
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I've opened up a bug at Apple, but wanted to see if anyone else is having the same issue and if they figured out how to fix.

Comment: Hey Mavro, I am seeing this issue as well. It's in a separate iOS framework we are compiling. Works fine on Xcode 9.4.1 and produces a very similar massive list of `duplicate input file` errors. I am at a loss as to how to address it.

Comment: The Apple Bug Reporter shows my bug submission as a duplicate and is currently open -- so it seems like Apple is aware of the issue.

Comment: For the last error if any output files are specified, they all must be please check stackoverflow.com/a/52493911/1728959. This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project folder contains directories with space in name e.g. "Hello World".
You should rename all founded directories (even without source code) into name without spaces, e.g. "HelloWorld" or "Hello-World".

```
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Tests.build'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Extension.build'
<unknown>:0: error: duplicate input file 'Home'
```

'Tests.build', 'Extension.build', 'Home' are part of name after space.
So, with this hack you can solve all errors, except last issue:

```
"<unknown>:0: error: if any output files are specified, they all must be"
```

But anyway, I didn't a find solution for last error.

**UPDATE:**

Last error fixed by removing spaces in Product Name in Build Settings for your target (don't confuse with Display Name in Info.plist, it can contain spaces)

Comment: Nice work!  You found the issue with this XCODE 10 build -- I confirmed that is the issue but unfortunately I have some POD files I don't have control over that also have spaces... will add this to the Apple bug report.  Seems like a regression bug since XCODE 9.4.1 it handled spaces.

Comment: I figured out how to build again -- I had the MacOS project path in the Framework Search Path, removing that allowed me to successfully build the MacOS target after building the iOS target.

Comment: For the last error `if any output files are specified, they all must be` please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52493911/1728959. This was the solution for me.